# pandas dataframe loc failing to identify correct name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

First, I had to import some data by running the following:

```
from eliteprospect import eliteprospect_scraper as ep
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nhl_2020 = ep.getPlayers('nhl', '2019-20')
players = pd.concat([nhl_2020])
lakings = players.loc[players['team'] == 'Los Angeles Kings']
lakingsdefs = lakings.loc[lakings['fw_def'] == 'DEF']
lakingsdefs_pos = lakingsdefs[['playername','position']]
##print(lakingsdefs_pos)
```

Then, I end up having a very simple dataframe created with Pandas as follows:

```
                            playername position
                178      Drew Doughty         D
                295       Sean Walker         D
                382          Matt Roy         D
                403        Ben Hutton         D
                554  Kurtis MacDermid         D
                632       Joakim Ryan         D
                743    Mikey Anderson         D
                758        Paul LaDue         D
                859   Tobias Björnfot         D
                876       Kale Clague         D
```

I tried the following code to pick out 'Joakim Ryan.'

```
print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'] == 'Joakim Ryan'])
```

Unfortunately, it failed to pick out the row with 'Joakim Ryan' in it.

On the other hand, when I tried the same thing with 'position,' it does seem to work.

```
print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['position'] == 'D'])
```

Just prints out the entire list, as it should.

I am hoping to output something like the following:

```
       playername position
632  Joakim Ryan         D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try `.str.contains()` method;

```
lakingsdefs_pos[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'].str.contains('Joakim Ryan')]#If you only have the two columns

lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'].str.contains('Joakim Ryan'),['playername','position']]#If you have other columns other than position and playername


      playername   position
632  Joakim Ryan        D
```

Comment: Thank you.  The first one is pretty much what I wanted, but the output formatting is different from the output format of `print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['position'] == 'D'])`.

Comment: `print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'].str.contains('Joakim Ryan'),'playername'])` should output the same format. Your print returns moreless a series. They cant be the same. So is your question answered?

Comment: `print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'].str.contains('Joakim Ryan'),'playername'])` outputs only his name.  I was hoping to output something I just added to the main text.

Comment: My first answer; `lakingsdefs_pos[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'].str.contains('Joakim Ryan')]` will do the same. The output will ony be different if you have more columns. Do you have more columns? We can work on that

Comment: Please see my edits. I have included an option for cases where you have multiple columns.

Comment: @stratofortress does that help?

Comment: this is perfect. thank you so much. sorry ive been gone for a while.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you know why `print(lakingsdefs_pos.loc[lakingsdefs_pos['playername'] == 'Joakim Ryan'])` did not work but `.str.contains()` does?

Comment: .loc[] is primarily label based, but `may` also be used with a boolean array. It works as follows; `df.loc[row selection, column selection]`. If using boolean, it must be the same as row axis.Have a read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html